# Tomcat 8 can not find com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener class

Tags: tomcat, primefaces, jsf-2

I am new to JSF and have a noob issue. I am playing with a tutorial found at http://javatutorialspot.com/jsf2/primefaces/primefaces-hello-world/ . When I run it on Tomcat 7 everything works just fine. As soon as I switch targeted runtime environment to Tomcat 8 I get the following exception

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:518)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:499)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My build path has two jar files: jsf-api-2.2.0 jar and jsf-impl-2.2.0.jar as part of a user library.

Runtime configuration has my user library as well.

Any ideas why Tomcat 8 wouldn't find com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener class?

Answer (score -2):

You need to updated your dependencies and Tomcat web.xml. You can find the solution by going to this link below: https://musingsinjava.wordpress.com/2014/11/02/enabling-jsf-2-2-and-cdi-1-2-on-tomcat-8/